# How to assign a variable name to each index of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public string[] TestResults = new string[8];
```

I want to assign each item of the array above to a variable. For example,

```
TestName = TestResults[0];
```

I am getting the message: A field initializer cannot reference the non static field, method or property" when I do the following:

```
public string TestName = TestResults[0];
```

Please suggest me how can I resolve this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. :))

Comment: [C# 7 adds the ability to return by reference and to store references in local variables](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/128/c-sharp-7-ref-returns-ref-locals-and-how-to-use-them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in a variable initializer, basically... although the value would be null anyway. You can't refer to `this` within a variable initializer, so you'd have to write:

```
public class Foo 
{
    // I hope your fields aren't really public...
    public string[] TestResults = new string[8];

    public string TestName;

    public Foo()
    {
        TestName = TestResults[0];
    }
}
```

Note that this would only retrieve the value *at construction* anyway. It wouldn't associate the variable itself with the first element in the array; either could change without affecting the other. If you want `TestName` to *always* be associated with `TestResults[0]` you might want to use a property instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    // I hope your fields aren't really public...
    public string[] TestResults = new string[8];

    public string TestName
    {
        get { return TestResults[0]; }
        set { TestResults[0] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to assume that, if your code worked, `TestName` becomes an alias for `TestResults[0]`, such that reading from or writing to that variable also changes the array. This is not the case.

What you can do, is using a property for this:

```
public string[] TestResults;

public MyClass()
{
    TestResults = new string[8];
}

public string TestName
{
    get { return TestResults[0]; }
    set { TestResults[0] = value; }
}
```

Comment: You could even make it an indexer property to avoid repetition (-:

Comment: @Henk Holterman: The idea is clearly to provide a semantically more meaningful name to the array element. An indexer would just expose what the array itself already exposes: an ordered sequence of eight string with no special semantic meaning. I would create a property for each array element and hide the array completely.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: For me, a friendly face like `(-:` indicates friendliness, not irony or sarcasm. And I disagree with your friendly suggestion :-P

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have a synonym for the index of the array you can use the following:

```
public string TestName
{
    get { return TestResults[0]; }
    set { TestResults[0] = value; }
}
```

This creates a set of methods called a property that are called in a syntax similar to a variable. You can drop the `set` part if you don't want write access externally.

If you want a copy of the variable you will need to write to it at some other point such as in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because

```
public string TestName = TestResults[0];
```

Will set TestName to the same instance of string that is stored in TestResults[0]. In other words, TestName will be a reference to the object stored in TestResults[0], not a reference to the memory address that is TestResults[0].

Depending on how your code is set up, I would just use properties and their getters:

```
public string TestName
{
    get { return TestResults[0]; }
}
```